# WARNING: JGRP000014: Discovery.timeout has been deprecated: GMS.join_timeout should be used instead

Tags: java, jgroups

```
WARNING: JGRP000014: Discovery.timeout has been deprecated: GMS.join_timeout should be used instead
```

why am I getting this if it's not defined directly by me? at least I don't think it is, looks like we're using the `GMS.join_timeout`

Here's how this one is configured

```
        log().info(
            "Starting JChannel for Distributable Sessions config:{} with channel name of {}",
            configString,
            channelName
        );
        jChannel = new JChannel(new PlainConfigurator(configString));

        jChannel.connect(channelName);
        replicatedSessionIds = new ReplicatedHashMap<>( jChannel );

        sessionIds = replicatedSessionIds;

        if (! sessionDistributedTest )
        {
            replicatedSessionIds.start(TIME_OUT);
        }
```

and the output of that log messsage

```
Starting JChannel for Distributable Sessions config:TCP(bind_addr=172.20.0.4;bind_port=7800;max_bundle_size=200000):TCPPING(timeout=3000;initial_hosts=dex.master[7800],dex.slave[7800];port_range=1):VERIFY_SUSPECT(timeout=1500):pbcast.NAKACK2(use_mcast_xmit=false;discard_delivered_msgs=true):pbcast.STABLE(stability_delay=1000;desired_avg_gossip=50000;max_bytes=400000):pbcast.GMS(print_local_addr=true;join_timeout=2000;view_bundling=true):pbcast.STATE_SOCK with channel name of Dex_SpringSecurity_Cluster_Dev
```

`jgroups 3.6.13`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually *do* define `timeout` in `configString` passed to the channel constructor: `TCPPING.timeout`.

I have 2 suggestions for you:

- Switch to XML based configuration; plain-text configuration will not be supported any longer in 4.0
- Use `tcp.xml` shipped with 3.6.13 and modify it according to you liking. Your config looks a bit dated.

Comment: does 4.0 support "Java Config" so I don't have to use any textual format? I've been trying to kill off XML in our code (and yes this is probably very old we have 3 other xml configs)

Comment: Yes, of course you can always use programmatic configuration. This is available in addition to XML configuration.